# Store and Restore event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler

Please help to fix my function,  store event of one element and delete them, then re-install;

I don't know where is the problem, the function will only delete the event of element and will not restore.

Please help to fix.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="a">a</a>
<a href="#" id="b">b</a>​
```

JS

```
$("#a").hover(function(){alert("test")});

$("#b").click(function(){
    Test_Handle('#a');
}

function Test_Handle(id) {
         target = $(id);
        if($.hasData(target.get(0))){    //  if the elment has event || target = element
            target[0].event_name = [];
            target[0].event_handler = [];

            events = $._data(target.get(0), 'events');  // take all events of the element

            $.each(events, function(event_name, event_handler){ 
                target[0].event_name.push(event_name);
                target[0].event_handler.push(event_handler);
            });  //store the events

            target.off();  // delete the events
        }else{    // has the elment no event
            for(var i=0; i < target[0].event_handler.length; i++){
                target.on(target[0].event_name[i], target[0].event_handler[i]);
            }  // re-store the events

            target[0].event_name = [];
            target[0].event_handler = [];  //reset
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it, when you iterate through the events `event_handler` is actually an array of the handlers of that event (an event can have many handlers attached). So you need to save those handlers in one array for each of the events, so you can re-attach them later.

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/JELsT/4/):

```
function Test_Handle(id) {
    target = $(id);
    events = $._data(target[0], 'events');
    if(events!=undefined){   
        target[0].event_name = [];
        target[0].event_handler = [];        
        $.each(events, function(event_name, event_handler){
            target[0].event_name.push(event_name);
            var _handlers=[];
            for(var i=0;i<event_handler.length;i++){
                _handlers.push(event_handler[i].handler);
            }
            target[0].event_handler.push(_handlers);          
        });  //store the events
        target.off();  // delete the events
    }else{    // has the elment no event
        for(var i=0; i < target[0].event_handler.length; i++){
            for(var ii=0;ii<target[0].event_handler[i].length;ii++){
                target.on(target[0].event_name[i], target[0].event_handler[i][ii]);
            }          
        }  // re-store the events
        target[0].event_name = [];
        target[0].event_handler = [];  //reset
    }
}

$("#a").hover(function(){alert("test")});

$("#b").click(function(){
    Test_Handle('#a');
});
```

​

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JELsT/4/)

Comment: I have one additional question, do you think this function will take a lot of performance and will obviously slow the loading processing time? I found another way to deal with it. Like, if ($this.data('executing')) return; then $this.data('executing', true). Which way do you think it is better??

Comment: I don't think that this function can impact the performance of your application, however maybe it would be better to replace the first "if" (if($.hasData(target.get(0))){) for this: "if($._data(target[0], 'events')!=undefined){" . Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JELsT/4/